# Django change_password NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/change/

Tags: django, django-urls, change-password

I have the following url config in accounts/urls.py:

```
url(r'^password/change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
{'template_name': 'change_password.html'}, name='password_change'),
url(r'^password/change/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',
name='password_change_done'),
```

But if I call the password-change url I get the following

> error: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/change/ Reverse for
>   'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

If the user modified his password, it is to be logged out and login again.

Thanks a lot.

edit, traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/change/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 3.4.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'djangular',
 'djcelery',
 'accounts',
 'system_utils',
 'alert_system',
 'proj',
 'django_cleanup')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_change
  261.         post_change_redirect = reverse('password_change_done')
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  546.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/peter/Projekte/proj-hoster/proj-hoster-env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  463.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/change/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Looks like it did not try any patterns. Can you show the root url conf ?

Comment: in the root url: url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts'), name='account'),

Comment: Try changing `name='password-change-done'` to `name='password_change_done'` in your accounts/urls.py.

Comment: Done, the error remains...

Comment: In that case let's take a look at your full traceback)
(with line numbers)

Comment: added in question post.

Comment: How are you adding `accounts/urls.py` to your main `urls.py`?

Comment: in the root url: url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts'), name='account'),

Comment: Can you paste the `views.py` code? It is saying that it is trying to redirect, but can't.

Comment: rly? its the default django password_change view in: .../lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Comment: As it's namespaced, have you tried reversing 'accounts:password_change_done' ?

Comment: I have: 'accounts:password_change' because it call the default django view to change password(old, new, new - password). The password_change template called: 'accounts:password_change' in form post. I only have a different template... for change passwords.

Answer (score 2):

One of the references to 'password-change-done' has dashes, the other has underscores. It's likely something to do with that!

Comment: Unfortunately not :-(

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is a *very* old question, but I had the same error yesterday. I think the namespace is the problem. Once you've namespaced the urls, they'll all need to be prefixed with the name of the namespace (in your case "accounts") and a colon. If you look at the code for the `password_change` view, it (conditionally) redirects based on a url of 'password_change_done'. Because that url hasn't been decorated with your namespace, it can't be found. Drop the namespace, ensure that your url references no longer have it and you should be OK.