# Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

## Background

I am trying to customize the authentication views in a Django project, but I can't seem to get the customized password_change view to run. I use Django 1.8.2 and Python 2.7.

The `urls.py` of my module `userauth` looks like the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'userauth/login.html'},
        name='userauth_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout', {'next_page': '/'},
        name='userauth_logout'),
    url(r'^password-change/$', 'password_change',
        {'template_name': 'userauth/password_change_form.html'},
        name='userauth_password_change'),
    url(r'^password-change-done/$', 'password_change_done',
        {'template_name': 'userauth/password_change_done.html'},
        name='userauth_password_change_done'),
)
```

this is referenced in the main `urls.py` as this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('userauth.urls')),
]
```

The template of my `userauth/password_change_form.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ block.super }} - Change Password{% endblock %}

{% block toggle_login %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'userauth_password_change' %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Change password"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And the template for `userauth/password_change_done.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ block.super }} - Password change successful{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Your password has been changed successfully.</p>
<a href="{% url 'products_product_index' %}">Back to your Account</a>
{% endblock %}
```

## The Problem

When I open the `'password_change_done'` page (at /account/password-change-done), then everything is fine.

But at `'password-change'` (/accunt/password-change) I am getting this error:

> **NoReverseMatch at /account/password-change/**
>
> Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

## What I tried

I have no idea, why this should be happening.

1. I tried removing the single quotes from  `url 'userauth_password_change'`
2. I made sure the `password-change-done`page exists in urls.py and is available
3. I read the solutions at [Reverse for '*' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842389/reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found), [Django: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336076/django-reverse-for-detail-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-n), [Django change_password NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/change/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196678/django-change-password-noreversematch-at-accounts-password-change) (and a few more, I tried all the solutions there, but I can't find a problem in my own code)

**Any help is appreciated. Thank you!**

Comment: When I change the name of        `name='userauth_password_change_done'` to `name='password_change_done'` it works. why is that? Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was, that the in the urls.py the name of the password_change_done link **must** be `'password_change_done'`:

```
url(r'^password-change-done/$', 'password_change_done',
    {'template_name': 'userauth/password_change_done.html'},
    name='password_change_done'),
```

I had a look into `django.contrib.auth.views.password_change` (which was creating the problem) and realized, that the the url `'password_change_done'` is hardcoded there in Django 1.8.2.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so the suggested solution for me didn't work here. I'm using Django 1.8.8 in an application with a specific app label, so I need to specify a url in a template like this e.g. app_label:url_name. This meant the reverse for password_change_done would never work since it's app_label:password_change_done.

But thankfully there's a solution: 'post_change_redirect'. Hence I specified password_change like this:

```
url(r'^password_change$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name': 'password_change.html', 'post_change_redirect': 'app_label:password_change_done'}, name='password_change'),
```

I'm sure others could use this to overcome the problem above and still keep their own custom url name.

Comment: But this looks more as workaround, where I can find this in the documentation? and this is fixed in django 1.10 (because in django 1.9 is the same as in 1.8.8).

Answer (score 3):

In some section you call the url named "password_change_done"

the correct name is: "userauth_password_change_done"

Comment: Where is that? I can't find to use it incorrectly. should it be `name='password_change_done'` instead?

Comment: Could you add the view named "password_change"?

Comment: Actually I don't have a custom view for `password_change`. It though it  just uses `'django.contrib.auth.views-password_change'`, because of the lin `urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',. Do I understand that wrong?

Comment: It's actually vice versa: `'userauth_password_change_done'` is the **incorrect** url `name`, and it has to be `'password_change_done'`. Thanks for your help, pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

You need delete single quotes around the view name

```
{% url password_change_done %}
```

instead of

```
{% url 'password_change_done' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same kind of problem. The reason is the "password_change_done" is hard code in the auth.views, so I extense the class base on the auth.views.PasswordChangeView。

the auth.views.PasswordChangeView:

```
class PasswordChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
......
success_url = reverse_lazy('password_change_done')
```

the MyPasswordChangeView:

```
class MyPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app_label:password_change_done')
```

just overide the `success_url`.

and use MyPasswordChangeView in the urlpattern. Now, everything is ok.

Comment: more convenient way，just override the class var `success_url` in the `as_view()`: `path('settings/password/',
         auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_change.html',
             success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_change_done')),
         name='password_change', ),`

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are using

> app_name

and trying to overwrite default template for update/change password you have to tell that Django:

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('password_change/',
         auth_view.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
             template_name='registration/password_change_form.html',
             success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),

    path('password_change/done/',
         auth_view.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='registration/password_change_done.html'), name='password_change_done'),
]
```